# Assign value to closest tr with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have below code where i assign value of AJAX returns to nearest class td.

```
$(document).off('change', '.inventoryitem_id').on('change', '.inventoryitem_id', function() {

    var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('.inventoryitem_id').find(":selected").val();

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/inventory/items/get/" + id,
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) {

            $(this).closest('tr').find('.item_rate').first().val(data.inventoryitem_purchase_price);
            $(this).closest('tr').find('.item_description').first().val(data.inventoryitem_description);

     
        }
    });

});
```

Table have row with `.inventoryitem_id`, `.item_rate`, `.item_description`.

I could able to get `id` when selected, pass it to AJAX and get returned data,

But i could not assing values to `.item_rate` or `.item_description`

Whats wrong here?

Comment: Hi, save `$(this).closest('tr')` in some variable outside your ajax call i.e : `var selector = $(this).closest('tr')` and then use it inside ajax success i.e : `selector.find(..`

Comment: @Swati, thanks. It worked.